# Should links satisfy the "what have you tried?" aspect of good questions?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

**Failed Audit**

- [Review Audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3634512)
- [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565126/horizontal-scrolling-and-vertical-scrolling-in-jquerymobile)

**Things I've Learned**

- I was going too fast through the review queue, and I've since slowed down.
- I tried to review a question where I wasn't a subject matter expert, and I've since started skipping more questions.

**My Logic**

I voted to close this question because I didn't think that saying, and I'm paraphrasing here:

> I didn't understand the code at [this link](http://developingwithstyle.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/jquery-mobile-swipe-up-down-left-right.html).
>
> I couldn't figure out how to use the code at [this link](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/).

qualified as meeting the ["what have you tried?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) aspect of good questions.

**Questions**

1. What would you have done on this review audit?
2. In general, do questions that provide links to libraries that don't solve the asker's problem satisfy the "what have you tried?" aspect of good questions?
3. If not, what is the appropriate action for this type of question (e.g. close, edit, comment)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Honestly I would have voted to close that question as well...

I probably would have used:

> "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of
>   the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't
>   work, and the expected results."

or

> "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe
>   the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the
>   question itself."

The question should have shown the attempted code in the question itself, and pointed directly to what wasn't understood, what wasn't working, and how it was expected to work.

Linking to a library or tutorial isn't really any different from linking to a jsFiddle or  personal site, which have been shown to be acceptable as additional resources, but questions are expected to be able to stand on their own without them.

I suspect the question survived because it had a bounty on it, it was apparently something a few users were interested in, and it attracted a couple of good answers.

Comment: I wonder if questions with bounties should be excluded from being potential review audits. The bounty was [open for two days](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/156227/bounty-start-date-for-question-id-20565126) when the question came up as a review audit for me. It seems like the bounty might skew the question toward getting more upvotes than it otherwise would

Comment: @godel9 That's a good point, the audit algorithm still needs some work... Don't worry about the audit though, if you only miss one in a great while you should be fine.